# Installing different keyboard layout on live debian image

Tags: linux, keyboard, debian, keyboard-layout, console

I've downloaded a debian vm image for some testing: http://exploit-exercises.com/download (280mb)

It's a Debian Squeeze machine. I want to use the Belgian layout (which is AZERTY) in stead of the default QWERTY. There is no X server installed.

What I've tried (everything as root)

- `setxkbmap be` -> 'command not found'
- `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` -> runs fine, but keyboard stays in QWERTY after selecting Belgium keyboard
- `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` -> "'console-data' is not installed and no info is available"
- `apt-get install console-data` -> package 'console-data' has no installation candidate. I also ran `apt-get update` and my apt list contains the debian urls.
- edit `/etc/default/keyboard` manually. I then read I should restart `/etc/init.d/hal`, but that service doesn't exist
- some other things I can't remember
- `locale-gen fr_FR` -> It says "Generating locales", but only shows en_US.UTF-8. No fr_FR to be found.
- `dpkg-reconfigure locales` The first list has all the locales where I select fr_Fr. The second screen (default locale) only gives en_US as option.

What else can I try?

Comment: wait, there's no X installed? is it just a linux console without a desktop manager?

Comment: That's right, no desktop manager

Answer (score 7):

I got it working by doing this:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install console-data
```

console-data appears to run automatically, so select "choose from full list" -> AZERTY

Answer (score 3):

For a linux console use this command:

```
loadkeys fr
```

and it will set the AZERTY keyboard

Comment: `loadkeys fr` -> "cannot open file fr" (the same for 'be')

Comment: Try adding locale first: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89976/how-to-change-the-default-locale-in-ubuntu-10-10-server

Comment: I've added two things I tried. (I can't reboot because it's a live CD). Still QWERTY...

Comment: 'sudo loadkeys fr' for me in raspberry pi raspbian stretch

Comment: `loadkeys fr` -> "cannot open file fr" (the same for 'be'): I installed `console-data` first, as suggested by @Dauntless